# How to upgrade dependency packages which have vulnerabilities

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

In our company we use veracode to scan our code and this tool give us a summary report at the end with the vulnerabilities found on our source code or dependencies.

I have created a new SPFx webpart, empty! just the basic hello world, and even then the tool found one vulnerability.

Component: validator
Version: 8.2.0
Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS): validator is vulnerable to regular expression denial of service (ReDoS) attacks. A malicious user can pass a long URI to the `isDataURI()` function to cause a ReDoS attack.
Link: https://sca.analysiscenter.veracode.com/vulnerability-database/security/sca/vulnerability/sid-7078/summary

When checking the dependency tree I found this:

```
├─┬ @microsoft/sp-build-web@1.12.1
│ └─┬ @microsoft/sp-build-core-tasks@1.12.1
│   └─┬ azure-storage@2.10.4
│     └── validator@9.4.1
└─┬ @microsoft/sp-module-interfaces@1.12.1
  └─┬ z-schema@3.18.4
    └── validator@8.2.0
```

If I understand correctly, I cant upgrade it myself because it may break the sp-module-interfaces.

Is there something I can do to update this package?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade the package that another package you don't control depends on, you're effectively rolling the dice it won't break that other one.

> If I understand correctly, I cant upgrade it myself because it may break the sp-module-interfaces.

Correct, you can't update it safely (ie: without side effects).

> Is there something I can do to update this package?

Not really... technically you can upgrade the other package's **sp-module-interface** dependency tree and make sure things still work, then use your internal one. But practically speaking, this isn't possible because you don't have access to the **sp-module-interfaces** package it's not made available to us.